# Getting wrong path name in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to get the exact path of the active word document. I have written the below code. The code works fine if one word document is open, but when I open a second document and run it the path shows as "My Documents". Even in the first document, if I run now it shows "My Documents". The code is:

```
Sub NewMenuMacro()
   Dim myMenuItem As Object

    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim folderName
    folderName = "..\.."
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Dim fullpath
     fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Me.Application.ActiveDocument)

  If fso.FileExists(fullpath) Then
  Dim objFile
        ' fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Me.Application.ActiveDocument)
     Set objFile = fso.GetFile(fullpath)
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs (objFile.path)
    fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)

   Else
    ActiveDocument.Save
    fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Me.Application.ActiveDocument)
   End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213182%28office.11%29.aspx) property.

```
fullpath = Me.Application.ActiveDocument.FullName
```